# static_assert negative integer

Tags: c++, static-assert

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int fact>
constexpr int pow2T()
{
    static_assert(fact < 0, "error");
return fact == 0 ? 1 : pow2T<fact - 1>() * 2;
}

constexpr int e2 = pow2T<2>();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << e2 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Trying to implement `x^2` static calculation with argument static checking.
Assertion fails.. why!?

> /home/serj/work/untitled/main.cpp:-1: In function 'constexpr int pow2T() [with int fact = 2]':
>
> /home/serj/work/untitled/main.cpp:-1: In function 'constexpr int pow2T() [with int fact = 1]':
>
> ...

Comment: Is  `fact < 0` a typo?

Comment: static_assert does the exact contrary of what you think! It fails if the condition is false. It asserts that the condition is true.

Comment: Note, you can use iteration (loops) instead of recursive function calls if you upgrade to a C++14 compiler.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: or just `(1u << fact)` (and that works for older compiler too ^_^).

Answer (score 7):

[`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) fails if condition is `false`. Obviously, `1 < 0` and `2 < 0` are both false.

BTW, this function computes `2^x`, not `x^2`

Answer (score 3):

The 2 branches are evaluated, you have to do specialization:

```
template <int fact>
constexpr int pow2T()
{
    static_assert(fact >= 0, "error");
    return pow2T<fact - 1>() * 2;
}

template <>
constexpr int pow2T<0>()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: My compiler agrees with you. But could you say why ?: version does not work as expected? Taking into account I'm trying to calculate only powT(2).

Comment: `pow2T<2>` requires `pow2T<1>` which requires `pow2T<0>`. But `pow2T<0>` also requires `pow2T<-1>` as the 2 branches are instranciated (even if it is not evaluated).